# Meaning of "swindle" in "…while four to five days in London would be suitable to swindle across the streets"

Tags: meaning

I came across this sentence in a blog. Is the 'swindle' being used correctly? If yes, what does it mean in this sentence?

> In most cases, three to four days in Paris would be enough to skim through the city, while four to five days in London would be suitable to swindle across the streets. However, if there are no budget constraints a week or two will be enough for both cities.

The blog where I found this sentence. [London vs Paris: What’s the Difference? [City Comparison]](https://viatravelers.com/london-vs-paris/)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about a one-off non-standard usage from [Alex Kroeger](https://viatravelers.com/author/alex/), who is clearly not a native Anglophone

Answer (score 5):

The author is describing the tourist on a strict budget. In Paris he is skimming through it, not stopping to shop or buy anything. The tourist in London he describes as swindling, merely as a light jest, as doing his best to get what he can for little or no money. As if they might be cheating vendors in order to get by, again, as a light jest.

There is no dictionary usage I can find where swindling is used as an expression to mean spending time exploring or taking in the sights. I'll be delighted to hear of an actual usage as such.

Comment: Perhaps someone who knows Dutch (probably the writer's native tongue) might know a Dutch verb that "explains" the clearly incorrect choice of the English verb here. Personally, I find "sightseeing on a restricted budget" unconvincing for both ***skim*** and ***swindle***. But ***skimp*** is in that general semantic territory.

Comment: Great idea. I would be delighted to see that.